# Reading from csv file

Tags: python, pandas

How to read the first cell from my csv file and store it as a variable

for example, my list is

| header 1 | header 2 |
| --- | --- |
| AM |  |
| Depth | Value |
| 10 | 20 |
| 30 | 122 |
| 60 | 222 |

how can I read the (AM) cell and store it as "x" variable?
and how I can I ignore AM cell later on and start my data frame from my headers (Depth, value)?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get a specific row/column using indexing. `iloc` should be able to help.

For example, `df.iloc[0,0]` returns `AM`.

Also, `pandas.read_csv` allows you to skip rows when reading the data, You can use `pd.read_csv("test.csv", sep="\t",skiprows=1)` to skip first row.

Result:

```
0     10     20
1     30    122
2     60    222
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I am using dummy csv file which is generated using data you posted in this question.

```
import pandas as pd
# read data 
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
```

File contents are as follows:

```
    header 1   header 2
0   AM         NaN
1   Depth      Value
2   10         20
3   30         122
4   60         222
```

One can use usecols parameter to access different columns in the data. If you are interested in just first column in this case it can be just 0 or 1. Using 0 or 1 you can access individual columns in the data.

You can save contents of this to x or whichever variable you want as follows:

```
# Change usecols to load various columns in the data 
x = pd.read_csv('test.csv',usecols=[0])
```

Header:

```
# number of line which you want to use as a header set it using header parameter
pd.read_csv('test.csv',header=2)

    Depth   Value
0   10      20
1   30      122
2   60      222
```

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: @tripleee, I have now removed all the images and added code directly to answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `pd.read_csv` and then select the first row:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('your file.csv')
x = df.iloc[0]['header 1']
```

Then, to delete it, use `df.drop`:

```py
df.drop(0, inplace=True)
```